# sed move text in .txt to next line

Tags: windows, unix, csv, sed, cygwin

I am trying to parse out a text file that looks like the following:

```
EMPIRE,STATE,BLDG,CO,494202320000008,336,5,AVE,ENT,NEW,YORK,NY,10003,N,3/1/2012,TensionCode,VariableICAP,PFJICAP,Residential,%LBMPZone,L,9,146.0,,,10715.0956,,,--,,0,,,J,TripNumber,ServiceClass,PreviousAccountNumber,MinMonthlyDemand,TODCode,Profile,Tax,Muni,41,39,00000000000000,9952,54,Y,Non-Taxable,--,FromDate,ToDate,Use,Demand,BillAmt,12/29/2011,1/31/2012,4122520,6,936.00,$293,237.54
```

what I would like to see is the data stacked

```
- EMPIRE STATE BLDG CO
- 494202320000008
- 336 5 AVE ENT
- NEW YORK NY
```

and so on.  If anything, after each comma I would want the text following to go to a new txt line.  Ultimatly in regards to the last line where it states date from forward, I would like to have it in a txt file like

```
- From Date  ToDate    use     Demand   BillAmt
- 12/29/2011 1/31/2012 4122520 6,936.00 $293,237.54.
```

I am using cygwin on a windows XP machine.  Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Is this a database dump file? Maybe you should use `SQL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting the last line into a separate file:

```
echo -e "From Date\tToDate\tuse\tDemand\tBillAmt" > lastlinefile.txt
cat originalfile.txt | sed 's/,FromDate/~Fromdate/' | awk -v FS="~" '{print $2}' | sed 's/FromDate,ToDate,use,Demand,BillAmt,//' | sed 's/,/\t/' >> lastlinefile.txt
```

For the rest:

```
cat originalfile.txt | sed -r 's/,Fromdate[^\n]+//' | sed 's/,/\n/' | sed -r 's/$/\n\n' > nocommas.txt
```

Your mileage may vary as far as the first '\n' is concerned in the second command. It if doesn't work properly replace it with a space (assuming your data doesn't have spaces).

Or, if you like, a shell script to operate on a file and split it:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]
then echo "Usage: $0 filename.txt; exit; fi

echo -e "From Date\tToDate\tuse\tDemand\tBillAmt" > "$1_lastline.txt"
cat "$1" | sed 's/,FromDate/~Fromdate/' | awk -v FS="~" '{print $2}' | sed 's/FromDate,ToDate,use,Demand,BillAmt,//' | sed 's/,/\t/' >> "$1_lastline.txt"

cat "$1" | sed -r 's/,Fromdate[^\n]+//' | sed 's/,/\n/' | sed -r 's/$/\n\n' > "$1_fixed.txt"
```

Just paste it into a file and run it. It's been years since I used Cygwin... you may have to `chmod +x file` it first.

Comment: I know this can also be done with a sed script, but I have never dealt with that. Most of my sed usage is in chained shell commands (can't you tell), so that's what I'm giving you

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance, I am going to work with this and follow-up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm providing you two answers depending on how you wanted the file. The previous answer split it into two files, this one keeps it all in one file in the format:

```
EMPIRE
STATE
BLDG
CO
494202320000008
336
5
AVE
ENT
NEW
YORK
NY
From Date  ToDate    use     Demand   BillAmt
12/29/2011 1/31/2012 4122520 6,936.00 $293,237.54.
```

That's the best I can do with the delimiters have you set in place. If you'd have left it something like "EMPIRE STATE BUILDING CO,494202320000008,336 5 AVE ENT,NEW YORK,NY" it'd be a lot easier.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]
then echo "Usage: $0 filename.txt; exit; fi

cat "$1" | sed 's/,FromDate/~Fromdate/' | awk -v FS="~" '{gsub(",","\n",$1);print $1;print "FromDate\tToDate\tuse\tDemand\tBillAmt";gsub("FromDate,ToDate,use,Demand,BillAmt","",$2);gsub(",","\t",$2);print $2}' >> "$1_fixed.txt"
```

again, just paste it into a file and run it from Cygwin: `./filename.sh`